# Scraping website using Xpath selector with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch some data from a website, and I am using the code below:

```
def Xpath_tp(url):
  Dict_Headers = ({'User-Agent':
      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
      (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',\
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
  # Gets the requried data https browser's address bar
  webPage = requests.get(url,Dict_Headers)
  # Creating a soup Object from the html content
  Scraping = BeautifulSoup(webPage.content, "html.parser") 
  # Conveting Soup object to etree object for Xpath processing
  documentObjectModel = etree.HTML(str(Scraping)) 
  return [(documentObjectModel.xpath('//*[@id="tr-stock-page-content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]')[0].text),
          (documentObjectModel.xpath('//*[@id="tr-stock-page-content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span')[0].text),
          (documentObjectModel.xpath('//*[@id="tr-stock-page-content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')[0].text),
          (documentObjectModel.xpath('//*[@id="tr-stock-page-content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div')[0].text),
          (documentObjectModel.xpath('//*[@id="tr-stock-page-content"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div')[0].text)]

URL = 'https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/tsla/forecast'
print(Xpath_tp(URL))
```

I tried the same thing on Yahoo finance website (with different Xpaths), but this one says "list index out of range", and I guess it has something to do with [0] at the end of Xpath I am specifying, but I don't know why.

The expected output should be a list with the following elements: ['$211.93', 'Moderate Buy', '21 Buy', '9 Hold', '3 Sell']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Python - Webscraping Xpath Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656893/selenium-python-webscraping-xpath-error)

Comment: I don't think so. I don't want to use the selenium on account of it's slower than BeautifulSoup. Plus I think I have the right Xpaths in the code.

Comment: I suspect you don't actually have the right XPath expressions, and maybe you should try evaluating the XPaths in some interactive tool where you can play around with them more easily. Also, I really wonder if those XPath expressions selecting `div` elements by their (numeric) position really the best option? It's generally much more reliable to refer to elements by their id or by a string token contained in a class attribute, or something like that, rather than by position, which is liable to vary.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your exact expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically through an API call (which you can find using the console in your brwoser's Developer tab). It returns a JSON from which you can extract your target data.

In this case:

```
import json
import requests
url = " https://tr-frontend-cdn.azureedge.net/bff/prod/stock/tsla/payload.json?ver=1678406987078"
req = requests.get(url)

data = req.json()
infos = data['similar']['similar']
for info in infos:
    #the JSON contains more than just TSLA data
    if info['ticker']=="TSLA":
        target = info['analystRatings']['consensus']
        recs = [i for i in (target.items())][1:4]
        print(target['id'],target['priceTarget']['value'],recs[0],recs[1],recs[2])
```

Output:

```
moderateBuy 211.93 ('buy', 21) ('sell', 3)('hold', 9)
```

You can play with the output later, but your target data is there.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But it works for a single stock. When I try to loop over several stocks at a time, it gives a 404 error (req.status_code for every stock in a list is 404). Would you happen to know what it's about?

Comment: I already tried time.sleep(x) method but it does not work even with 60 second delay. I seems to have a problem with for loop, because when I copy the above code multiple times and run the code, it gives me the output for those stocks immediately.

Comment: @gugapoladashvili First, a 404 error indicates you're hammering the server too much. There quite a few question regarding this, so you should do some research. Another important thing - as I mentioned in the answer, the JSON covers more companies, not just TSLA so you may already have some of the information you're looking for.

Comment: I also tried this on some of the etfs on tipranks, but the url seems to be different for etfs and stocks, (for instance,     https://tr-frontend-cdn.azureedge.net/bff/prod/etf/xlp/payload.json?ver=1678406987078      does not work). Would you happen to know what url do I have to put in order to retrieve proper JSON data?

Comment: @gugapoladashvili Not off the top of my head. Let me look into this. Also, you may want to post it as a separate question, in case someone does know that off the top of their head!